# Link to a custom entity settings page does not appear at /admin/structure

Tags: 8, entities

I have several custom entities as part of a module. When I visit /admin/structure, one of the entities is not listed in the groups of setting, or in the lists. However, if I manually type, `/admin/structure/{entity}/settings/fields`, I can manage the fields, form and display. However, the "Settings" tab is missing.

Similarly, I can manually type `/admin/structure/{module}/{entity}` to see the entity list, but the link is missing. The entity list is missing the button to add a new entity because the entire #block-seven-local-actions div is missing. Manually typing `/admin/structure/{module}/{entity}/add` brings up the correct form, and the form works.

It appears the routes are present, but something is preventing some of the links from being displayed. There are no errors in the recent log messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please revise your file:

> yourmodule.links.menu.yml.

and verify if exists the parameter

> parent

A complete example

```
  yourmodule.admin_content:
  title: Content
  description: 'Find and manage content.'
  route_name: system.admin_content
  parent: system.admin_structure
  weight: -10
```

Comment: The entities were missing from that file. Adding them fixes the links not appearing on admin/structure. However, the link to add a new entity is still missing from the list page, and the "settings" tab is still missing at `/admin/structure/{entity}/settings/fields`

Comment: Did you check file routing.yml ?, because the "settings" tab might not exist for this entity.

Comment: Thanks. I needed to add entries to the tasks.yml and actions.yml files

Comment: Excellent. Congratulations :).